# Is there a tool for converting logs to source code lines?

Tags: logs, source-code, log-analysis

We can search -or grep - each line of the log separately to find the each line( or possible lines) of the source code, is there a tool to extract the whole lines of log?

**Edit 2**:

typical log lines are  :

```
 TIME  USER  MODULE: MESSAGE
```

and one example is

```
 12:00:00.000 AAA   BBB: Connection Failed from [XXX] IP [YYY] PORT [ZZZ]
```

and its source line is

```
logger(Connection Failed from [123] IP [456] PORT [789]);
```

message is grep-able in the source code, XXX YYY ZZZ are variable parameters

and the code base almost writern by C\C++ in linux.

Comment: Please [edit] this and be more specific: what 'logs' (what is their relation with the source code), what programming language and IDE?

Comment: I don't see any connection to source code here